# Comparing ARWorldMaps

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arworldmap

Is it possible to compare two ARWorldMaps? 
What I am trying to achieve is save a few world maps with anchors in them. 
Then when the user starts the application again, I intend to capture his current world map and compare it with the saved ones. 
If a match is found, the anchors corresponding to that map are loaded and shown.

Comment: Wouldn't the best "comparison" be the ability to localize? i.e. if you have Map A, B and C, with n-anchors each. If the current view matches with Map B that's the closest comparison and the n-anchors can be loaded no?

Comment: @pj_mukh Agreed, it would be great if you could shed some light on how to accomplish the view matching. Do I compare the feature points or is there any other way?